# In C#, when running async tasks in parallel, the last one runs again and again forever

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task

When reading an xml from the server, I have to run multiple database inserts, so to do it efficiently I'm trying to run the handling functions in parallel.

This works nicely but for some reason the last task runs again and again forever even though it is not called more than once (I checked it thoroughly in the debugger).

The code in question:

```
    static string sLast = "";
    static string sReadElement = "";
    static Dictionary<string, string> dctEvent;
    ...
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlReader xrReader = XmlReader.Create(GetDataStream(), new XmlReaderSettings() { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse });

        try
        {
            Dictionary<string, Task> dctEventTasks = new Dictionary<string, Task>();
            while (xrReader.Read())
            {
                switch (xrReader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        switch (xrReader.Name)
                        {
                            case "event":
                                dctEvent = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                                break;
                            ...
                            default:
                                sReadElement = xrReader.Name;
                                break;
                        }

                        break;

                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        ...
                        break;

                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                        switch (xrReader.Name)
                        {
                            ...
                            case "event":
                                if (!dctEvent.ContainsKey(dctEvent["gamenumber"]))
                                {
                                    Func<Task> func = async () =>  await HandleEvent(dctEvent, lstParticipants, lstPeriods);
                                    dctEventTasks.Add(dctEvent["gamenumber"], Task.Run(func));
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            Log("Last: " + sLast);
            Task.WhenAll(dctEventTasks.Values);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task HandleEvent(Dictionary<string, string> dctEvent, List<Dictionary<string, string>> lstParticipants, List<Dictionary<string, string>> lstPeriods)
    {
        ...
        Log("Finished handling event: " + dctEvent["gamenumber"]);
    }
```

Comment: are you sure you are not getting exception in one of those tasks? if any error happens you will not be notified (i.e program continues execution) and strange things will happen. try to put break point inside and see where you get errors

Comment: What happens if you just log instead of creating a taks. Is it logged only once?

Comment: yes, if i just log, it gets logged once.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
The problem was that dctEvent, lstParticiapnts and lstPeriods were static and shared through every run of the main while loop. So when the collections were edited the result would change for other async methods running parallel.
The solution was to clone the collections like so:

```
                            case "event":
                                if (!dctEventTasks.ContainsKey(dctEvent["gamenumber"]))
                                {
                                    var cdctEvent = dctEvent.ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key,
                                           entry => entry.Value);
                                    var clstParticipants = lstParticipants.ToList();
                                    var clstPeriods = lstPeriods.ToList();
                                    Func<Task> func = async () =>  await HandleEvent(cdctEvent, clstParticipants, clstPeriods);
                                    dctEventTasks.Add(dctEvent["gamenumber"], Task.Run(func));
                                }
                                break;
```